# How to added different time zone and date correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm added New York City, United States time and date but I don't have any idea for the how to add current date and time following time zones. dose any one know how do that correctly using HTML and JavaScript.

- New York City, United States
- London, United Kingdom
- Dubai, United Arab Emirates
- Sydney, Australia
- Mumbai, India

here is the **New York City, United States** time for I added code part

**html**

```
  <p class="date_time"><strong id="sec"></strong></p></div>
     <div class="dte-fnt "> Wednesday, November 23, 2022 </div>
```

**javascript**

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        //EST
        setInterval( function() {
          var estTime = new Date();
          var currentDateTimeCentralTimeZone = new Date(estTime.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Chicago' }));
          var seconds = currentDateTimeCentralTimeZone.getSeconds();
          var minutes = currentDateTimeCentralTimeZone.getMinutes();
          var hours =  currentDateTimeCentralTimeZone.getHours()+1;//new Date().getHours();
          var am_pm = currentDateTimeCentralTimeZone.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
    
          if (hours < 10){
            hours = "0" + hours;
          }
    
          if (minutes < 10){
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
          }
          if (seconds < 10){
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
          }
          var mid='PM';
          if(hours==0){ //At 00 hours we need to show 12 am
            hours=12;
          }
          else if(hours>12)
          {
            hours=hours%12;
            mid='AM';
          }
          var x3 = hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds +' '+am_pm
    // Add a leading zero to seconds value
          $("#sec").html(x3);
        },1000);
    
    
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: what is the expected date format?

Comment: @ericmp Like as Wednesday, November 23, 2022

Comment: Be careful in spelling JavaScript, to avoid collisions with Java. I fixed this occurrence.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thank you for the advice anyway, I apologize for my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Add a loop

You can loop through the time zones, and run your existing program in each time zone:

```js
const timeZones = [
  "America/Chicago",
  "Europe/London",
  // Add the other timeZones you want here, e.g. by looking through
  // https://github.com/formatjs/date-time-format-timezone/tree/master/src/data/timezones
]

timeZones.forEach(timeZone => {
  var estTime = new Date();
  var currentDateTimeCentralTimeZone = new Date(estTime.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: timeZone
  }));
  var seconds = currentDateTimeCentralTimeZone.getSeconds();
  var minutes = currentDateTimeCentralTimeZone.getMinutes();
  var hours = currentDateTimeCentralTimeZone.getHours();
  var am_pm = hours >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";

  if (hours < 10) {
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }

  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }
  var mid = 'PM'; 

  if (hours == 0) { //At 00 hours we need to show 12 am
    hours = 12;
  } else if (hours > 12) {
    hours = hours % 12;
    mid = 'AM';
  }
  var x3 = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ' + am_pm

  console.log(x3 + " in " + timeZone)
})
```

## You can remove some unused code

You are creating a variable `mid` but are not using it later. (It so happens that you seem to be setting AM/PM backwards in this variable.) So you can get rid of the lines that set the value of `mid`.

## Fix off-by-one error in `hours`

Currently you are adding 1 to `hours`, for no good reason. I have removed it in my copy of the code above.

## Fix formatting error in `hours` in early afternoon

You are also adding "0" to the start of `hours` for situations where hours is 0 to 9. You are *later* reducing `hours` modulo 12, to help get the 12-hour clock. However, I think you are doing these steps the wrong way round. If `hours` starts at, say, 14, it will not have "0" added to the beginning of it, but later it will undergo % 12, to give 2. However this will appear as "2" and not "02" as the adding-0 step has already been passed.

I suggest putting the `if (hours == 0)` code between the `var am_pm` and the `if (hours<10)`.

## Reposition this comment, to be above the relevant line of code:

```
// Add a leading zero to seconds value
```

## For real-life use, use a date-time library

Everything I have written here is just to help you learn to program. If you are planning to use this in production, you would be much better off using a library like `moment.js` or `luxon.js`. They are expertly maintained and have thought of hundreds of problems that could happen with date/time manipulation, and solved them skilfully.

This video explains nicely why creating your own date-time handler, for any reason other than curiosity or programming practice, is not worthwhile.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Date.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to display dates in any given [`IANA timezone`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

You can customize the date format using the options passed to the .toLocaleString() function.

```js
const timeZones = ['America/Chicago', 'America/New_York', 'Europe/London', 'Asia/Dubai', 'Australia/Sydney', 'Asia/Kolkata'];
const options = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', hour12: true, hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'};
const locale = 'en-US';

let now = new Date();

console.log('Timezone'.padEnd(22), 'Current Time')
for(let timeZone of timeZones) {
    console.log(timeZone.padEnd(22), now.toLocaleString(locale, { timeZone, ...options } ))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

I'd also suggest taking a look at the [`luxon`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) date/time library, this allows conversion of DateTime values to any timezone and allows great flexibility in the output format.

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;
const timeZones = ['America/Chicago', 'America/New_York', 'Europe/London', 'Asia/Dubai', 'Australia/Sydney', 'Asia/Kolkata'];

let now = DateTime.now();

console.log('Timezone'.padEnd(22), 'Current Time')
for(let timeZone of timeZones) {
    console.log(timeZone.padEnd(22), now.setZone(timeZone).toFormat('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.0.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-6ZJuab/UnRq1muTChgrVxJhSgygmL2GMLVmSJN7pcBEqJ1dWPbqN9CiZ6U3HrcApTIJsLnMgXYBYgtVkJ8fWiw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest to use a library for this, as dealing with timezones and offsets is quite complex. My suggestion is to use [`moment`](https://github.com/moment/moment) with its extension `moment-timezone`.
You'll have to check the documentation to understand it, but a basic example for you situation would be something like this:

```js
var moment = require('moment-timezone'); // make sure you install `moment` as well!

var date = moment(); // local datetime
var dateNewYork = moment('America/New_York'); // This won't work for every town, but New York is a standardized timezone indicator.

console.log(date.format('LLL'));
console.log(dateNewYork.format('LLL'));
```