# HTML JavaScript to add Date format not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I put the my html code to `Australia/Sydney Date format`,
but its not working correctly, it always `shown currant date`, like as **Friday, December 9, 2022** dose any one know the solution?

`Australia` date now  **Saturday, December 10, 2022**

Thank you

here is my code

```js
const datesausDiv = document.getElementById('date-div-aus');

function myDateFunction() {
  const now = new Date();
  const timeZones = ['Australia/Sydney'];
  const options = {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
  };
  const nowStr = now.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
  datesausDiv.innerHTML = nowStr;
}

setInterval(myDateFunction, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="date-div-aus"> </div>
```

Comment: `timeZones` isn't used?

Comment: Why you use `en-us` instead of `en-au` ?

Comment: @Arnau I used the `en-au`  but not a fixed

Comment: @0stone0 its used const timeZones = ['Australia/Sydney'];

Comment: So you define an array with some timezones string. How do you expect that to alter the actual result of `toLocalString`

Comment: Could you include, into your question, an example of the date time format you wish to see?

Comment: @acarlstein this format `Friday, December 9, 2022`

Comment: @core114 The format you just provided, `Friday, December 9, 2022`, is the one use in the US. Supposedly for the wiki I found, the format used in Australia is the same as in the United Kingdom and New Zealand which is `4 December 2022` or `2022-12-04 or 04/12/2022`; therefore, if we use `en-GB`, we obtain `Friday, 9 December 2022`.  I put my solution below with all the details.

Comment: The wording of the question is pretty confusing: are you trying to enter a time in your current timezone, and find out what time that corresponds to in Australia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording of the question is pretty confusing, but it sounds like you're trying to display the current date in Australia to users who are not necessarily in Australia.

You defined a "timezone" array but didn't do anything with it; it needs to be fed in as one of the options:

```js
const datesausDiv = document.getElementById('date-div-aus');

function myDateFunction() {
  const now = new Date();
  const options = {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    timeZone: "Australia/Sydney"
  };
  const nowStr = now.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
  datesausDiv.innerHTML = nowStr;
}

setInterval(myDateFunction, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="date-div-aus"> </div>
```

(Note: to the likely resigned chagrin of the residents of Perth, the above pretends that Australia has only one timezone.)

Comment: Hi, This one is worked for me, Thanks for your time and valuable answered

Answer (score 1):

The following demonstrates how you can present the same (current) time in different formats and for different global locations:

```js
const now = new Date();

console.log("Sydney:",now.toLocaleString('en-GB', {timeZone:"Australia/Sydney"}));
console.log("New York:",now.toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone:"America/New_York"}));
console.log("here:",now.toLocaleString());
```

```html
<div id="date-div-aus"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Australia), it says that "Australians typically write the date with the day leading, as in the United Kingdom and New Zealand".

This means that dates have these possible formats:

- 4 December 2022
- 2022-12-04 or 04/12/2022

Therefore, the only fix you need is to use `en-GB`.

Please let me know if this is what you were searching for, else provide an example of the format you wish the date to show up. Have a nice day.

```js
const datesausDiv = document.getElementById('date-div-aus');

function myDateFunction() {
  const now = new Date();
  const options = {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
  };
  const nowStr = now.toLocaleString('en-GB', options);
  datesausDiv.innerHTML = nowStr;
}

setInterval(myDateFunction, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="date-div-aus"> </div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answered, but Australian date is  not a  `9`  its should be a, thats a issue I faced  `Saturday, December 10, 2022`

Comment: @core114, Right now, here where I live, its Dec 9 at 9:31AM. In Australia, located in the other corner of the world, is Dec 10 at 3:31 AM. The time it will display, is dependent of where the code is run.

Comment: @core114, if you wish the date time to be the same as where you live, regardless of where a user might run the JS code above, you will have to use a different approach. You need a way to obtain the timestamp in Australia, maybe some REST full service online, or run a server in Australia, set with the time in Australia, where your code can obtain the date.

Comment: @core114 is this helpful to you so far?

Comment: Please refer this link  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74744441/8268644 , and there is a showing correct date Saturday, December 10, 2022, I'm not idea that to implement to my html

Comment: @core114, I have my reservations about the solution shown there. The reason is that in the US we have more than one Timezone. We have Central Standard Time, Mountain Standard Time, Pacific Standard Time, Alaska Standard Time, and Hawaii-Aleutian Standard Time. Regardless, I can guarantee you, as someone living in the United States of America, right now as I'm typing this comment, that here it still December 9 of 2022, while in Australia its December 10, 2022.

Comment: @core114 here is the site [timeanddate](https://www.timeanddate.com/) which allows you to set the home location and find out the date and time.

Comment: The other alternative that came to my mind, its for you to detect the [location of the browser](https://blog.logrocket.com/detect-location-and-local-timezone-of-users-in-javascript-3d9523c011b9/) then modify the date in the way you want to display it that matches what is in Australia.

Comment: I Understood, But I'm showing my website through different date and time zone that's a issue, other time zone are ok, problem in a AUS I want to know how  can shown the Australian date zone in my HTML, When the USA user visit my website and he know the  Australian date today is 10 Saturday, December, USA DATE is  9 ,Saturday, December

Answer (score -2):

Split the string on each forward slash to get the day, month and year. Pass the year, month minus 1 and the day to the Date() constructor. The Date() constructor creates and returns a new Date object.

Comment: Can you please add using my code ,  so I'm not clear your solution